# How to enable Item reordering on a promoted Links list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, promoted-links, ordering

In SP2013 OOTB seatle master page, I made a links list and a promoted links list. In the links list, I have these options here

[image]

[image]

to change the order of the items. So this is enabled on a links list. However if I look for these things on my promoted links list, I don't see them. If I manually visit the reorder page, I can change the item values, and it seems to work only in the reorder form page. But the actual values in the Order field don't get updated. And in the tile  or all promoted links view, the order remains the same.

Does anyone know how I can enable the reorder feature for promoted links list?

Answer (score 1):

Promoted links do have an `order` property with every list item. You could specify the sequence number there.

The [article here](https://sharepointmike.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/promoted-links-sharepoint-2013/) has an example.

I normally prefer to open the quick edit view and change the order there, instead of modifying every list item on edit form.

Comment: @jcp I have already added the "real" solution! There is a field called Order, which can be used to specify the sequence. The link has just an example.

Comment: Uops. My fault. Will delete my comment now.